# Where did the /symbol-sync endpoint go?

Tags: symbols, ticker, stocktwits

Gentlefolk,

Because I backtest portfolios of stocks, it is useful to keep a historical record of ticker symbols. I typically do this with a daily reading of the `/symbol-sync` endpoint. For example for today, it would be: [`/symbol-sync/2018-02-11.csv`](https://api.stocktwits.com/symbol-sync/2018-02-11.csv). On Friday, Feb. 9th, it has started returning 404. Is this service discontinued by StockTwits? Has this become a fee based service?

Anon,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been added back. Sorry for the inconvenience.